# Print array with LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I got the following code and i am trying to print `teenAgerStudents` without the foreach i made after the LINQ line.
Can i add print in the LINQ line?
Can i print with another new LINQ line onstead the foreach?

```
class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student[] studentArray = {
                new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 18 } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 21 } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 25 } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 20 } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , Age = 31 } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 6, StudentName = "Chris",  Age = 17 } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 7, StudentName = "Rob",Age = 19  } ,
    };
        Student[] teenAgerStudents = studentArray.Where(s => s.Age > 12 && s.Age < 20).ToArray();

        foreach (var item in teenAgerStudents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.StudentName);
        }
};
```

Comment: Yes you can. And for simple cases it's fine. However, LINQ's performance is often a lot worse than writing the code. I tend to avoid it where possible unless I am absolutely sure performance is not, and will never become, a factor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will work:

```
studentArray.Where(s => s.Age > 12 && s.Age < 20)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(item.StudentName));
```

[Array.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2(v=vs.110).aspx) takes an `Action<T>` so it doesn't have a return value. If you need the array later on, you should stick to your old code.

Of course you can also still use the `ForEach` in a second statement:

```
List<Student> teenAgerStudent = studentArray.Where(s => s.Age > 12 && s.Age < 20).ToList();
teenAgerStudent.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.StudentName));
```

But that makes it less readable (in my opinion) so I would stick to a good old `foreach` loop in that case.

Comment: In the first case, just drop the ToArray() - it adds nothing.

Comment: @Zastai That wouldn't work, `ForEach` isn't defined for `IEnumerable`

Comment: My bad. That's what happens when I comment from my phone and can't quickly check the docs.

Comment: the second code is exactly what i was looking for, but it's not working, there is a red line (error) under the ForEach

Comment: @Apparantly it only works for `List<T>`, use `ToList` instead, then you'll have access  to `ForEach` method

Comment: @user3396397 Really? So you were looking for `teenAgerStudents.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.StudentName));`. Could you explain then the difference from `foreach (var s in teenAgerStudents) Console.WriteLine(s.StudentName));` other than being more inefficient?

Comment: @IvanStoev A matter of preference I suppose, I like a normal foreach (without braces) more too.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck The comment wasn't addressed to you:) Your answer is fine (if you replace `item` with `s` :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  // There's no need in materialization, i.e. "ToArray()"
  var target = studentArray 
    .Where(student => student.Age > 12 && student.Age < 20) // teen
    .Select(student => String.Format("Id: {0} Name: {1} Age {2}", 
              student.Id, student.Name, student.Age));

  // Printing out in one line (thanks to String.Join)
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, target));
```

Comment: This is a very unique method. Highlights the fact that `target` has not been executed and will be executed when really needed. +1.

Comment: But gathers the full set of results, wasting memory. Streaming results is much more scalable.

Comment: @Zastai: it depends on the data's size. Since the data is represented as an *array* (and so the entire data are in memory) I assumed that we have a sufficient memory for `String.Join` (if we read from, say, *file*, streaming would be a point)

Comment: Sample code in a question is often just a sample; I try not to base too much on it. But yes, with this array it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to use LINQ (a functional programming system) for side effects. I'd rather change the output foreach to something like that:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    teenAgerStudents.Select(s => s.StudentName));
```

Answer (score 1):

This line will print your teenAgerStudents names to console, one for each line.

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, studentArray.Where(s => s.Age > 12 && s.Age < 20).Select(s=>s.StudentName)));
```

It replaces both the `teenAgerStudents` initialization and the `foreach`.

If you still want to initialize your teenAgeStudents list because you need it, you could split the previous line in two

```
//get the teenager students in form of IEnumerable<Student>.
//cast it to array with .ToArray() after .Where() if needed.
var teenAgerStudents = studentArray.Where(s => s.Age > 12 && s.Age < 20);
//print only the students' names
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,teenAgerStudents.Select(s=>s.StudentName)));
```

Hope this helps.